# How to create JS Canvas Top Down Rain Effect or Reverse Warp Speed

Tags: javascript, canvas, particles

I am trying to figure out how to create a canvas rain effect, but from the top down perspective. Basically it's like you are looking down at the ground and you are watching the rain fall around you and fall slightly to the center at an angle, but it falls a short distance before ending. I am not seeing anything in searches except some game development that isn't canvas.

I am also looking for a solution that doesn't require an external library.

I have been able to modify some warp speed effect code to reverse the direction on the particles to fall to the background instead of off screen, but it is continuing to infinity toward the center and not redrawing or looping the particles that are coming from off screen.

I think it has something to do with the particles not dropping off screen in this part of the code. Am I on the right track here or can I not accomplish this effect with the current code?

```
clear();

  const cx = w / 2;
  const cy = h / 2;

  const count = stars.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const star = stars[i];

    const x = cx + star.x / (star.z * 0.001);
    const y = cy + star.y / (star.z * 0.001);

    if (x < 0 || x >= w || y < 0 || y >= h) {
      continue;
    }

    const d = star.z / 1000.0;
    const b = 1000 - d * d;

    putPixel(x, y, b);
  }
```

Here is the full code that I am looking at. Any help would be appreciated trying to figure this out.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const c = canvas.getContext("2d");

let w;
let h;

const setCanvasExtents = () => {
  w = document.body.clientWidth;
  h = document.body.clientHeight;
  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;
};

setCanvasExtents();

window.onresize = () => {
  setCanvasExtents();
};

const makeStars = count => {
  const out = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const s = {
      x: Math.random() * 1600 - 800,
      y: Math.random() * 900 - 450,
      z: Math.random() * 1000
    };
    out.push(s);
  }
  return out;
};

let stars = makeStars(1000);

const clear = () => {
  c.fillStyle = "black";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};

const putPixel = (x, y, brightness) => {
  const intensity = brightness * 255;
  const rgb = "rgb(" + intensity + "," + intensity + "," + intensity + ")";
  c.fillStyle = rgb;
  c.fillRect(x, y, 5, 5);
};

const moveStars = distance => {
  const count = stars.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const s = stars[i];
    s.z += distance;
    while (s.z <= 1) {
      s.z -= 10;
    }
  }
};

let prevTime;
const init = time => {
  prevTime = time;
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
};

const tick = time => {
  let elapsed = time - prevTime;
  prevTime = time;

  moveStars(elapsed * 1.5);

  clear();

  const cx = w / 2;
  const cy = h / 2;

  const count = stars.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const star = stars[i];

    const x = cx + star.x / (star.z * 0.001);
    const y = cy + star.y / (star.z * 0.001);

    if (x < 0 || x >= w || y < 0 || y >= h) {
      continue;
    }

    const d = star.z / 1000.0;
    const b = 1000 - d * d;

    putPixel(x, y, b);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
};

requestAnimationFrame(init);
```

```css
body {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0;margin: 0;"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides the effect you want to achieve, there are some other issues in the code:

- Hopefully this loop condition will never be true, as otherwise it will run infinitely:

  ```
  while (s.z <= 1) {
    s.z -= 10;
  }
  ```

  For what you want to achieve, this loop makes no sense. It should just be removed.
- The brightness parameter of `putPixel` expects a value between 0 and 1, but you pass it a value that will most often be outside that range:

  ```
  const d = star.z / 1000.0;
  const b = 1000 - d * d;
  ```

  You'd need to do `1 - d * d` there.

Then for your desired effect, you would need to:

- Keep the stars ordered by `z`, so you can easily extract stars that are too far, and remove them from the array
- Whenever you remove a star, add a new one that appears at the "next" `z` layer, i.e. the one the precedes the current first star (with least `z`).
- Allow drops to start somewhat outside the window, as they may still become visible when their distance increases
- It would be nice also to reduce the size of the "pixels" as they are more remote.

Here is your code updated with those ideas:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const c = canvas.getContext("2d");

let w;
let h;

const setCanvasExtents = () => {
  w = document.body.clientWidth;
  h = document.body.clientHeight;
  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;
};

setCanvasExtents();

window.onresize = () => {
  setCanvasExtents();
};

const makeStars = count => {
  const out = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    const star = {
      x: (Math.random() - 0.5) * w * 2,
      y: (Math.random() - 0.5) * h * 2,
      z: i * 1000 / count
    };
    out.push(star);
  }
  return out;
};

let stars = makeStars(4000);

const clear = () => {
  c.fillStyle = "black";
  c.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};

const putPixel = (x, y, brightness, size) => {
  const intensity = brightness * 255;
  const rgb = "rgb(" + intensity + "," + intensity + "," + intensity + ")";
  c.fillStyle = rgb;
  c.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
};

const moveStars = distance => {
  const count = stars.length;
  for (let star of stars) {
    star.z += distance;
  }
  for (let i = 0; stars[count - 1].z > 1000; i++) { 
    // Replace star
    stars.pop();
    stars.unshift({
      x: (Math.random() - 0.5) * w * 2,
      y: (Math.random() - 0.5) * h * 2,
      z: stars[0].z - 1000/count // keep z ordered
    });
  }
};

let prevTime;
const init = time => {
  prevTime = time;
  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
};

const tick = time => {
  let elapsed = time - prevTime;
  prevTime = time;

  moveStars(elapsed * 1.5);

  clear();

  const cx = w / 2;
  const cy = h / 2;

  const count = stars.length;
  for (let star of stars) {
    const x = cx + star.x / (star.z * 0.001);
    const y = cy + star.y / (star.z * 0.001);

    if (x < 0 || x >= w || y < 0 || y >= h) {
      continue;
    }

    const distance = star.z / 1000;
    const brightness = 1 - distance * distance;
    const size = brightness * 5;

    putPixel(x, y, brightness, size);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(tick);
};

requestAnimationFrame(init);
```

```css
body {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Really cool. I don't know why, but if you scroll this out of view or switch to another tab and then back again, it immediately begins to synchronize the animation so that it starts pulsating instead of "flowing" like it does from the start.

Comment: Yes, this is because the OP relies on elapsed time, and when the browser is occupied and does not call the routine, many stars get killed on the next round and lots of new stars start at the top. I will update the answer to not have the elapsed time dependency. It makes things worse than better.

Comment: Awesome. That is working now! I do have another issue. The goal is to put a picture underneath this to make it look like it is raining on a building, but when I try to change the color to transparent - it looks like the particles just keep building without clearing some of them and there are a lot of black lines. Any idea what is causing that? This is what I am using for my fillstyle   c.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)";

Comment: Sorry, but that is different question. If you cannot make that work, ask a new question about it.